# How to open Run dialog box in Windows server 2008 without using "WindowsKey+R"?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any shortcut key to open Run dialog box in windows server 2008 without using "WindowsKey+R" combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a normal shortcut file to it and then assign any keyboard shortcut to the shortcut file.